# About Excel Available add-ins

Tags: excel, add-in, excel-dna

I wrote a .xll plugin and selected Excel add in(COM and Excel Add-ins). It's No problem with plugin execution. But when I close my excel and open again, I found my .xll plugin is not excute and open COM and Excel Add-ins, I found it's unselect. I had to select again, it's could execution normal.
why my .xll plugin can not keep select status. Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel VBA Add-ins and XLL Add-ins both require an entry in the registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\
```

1. Can you see an entry in the registry ?
2. When the add-in is ticked, does it load and work as expected ?
3. Is there anything in your Disabled Items (Excel Options >
   Add-ins) change the Manage drop-down to "Disabled Items" and press
   Go ?

This page may provide a bit more information:
https://bettersolutions.com/excel/add-ins/registry-keys.htm

Comment: thank you for your help. I will check it later. Thank you.

Comment: the customer told me after they restart the computer it's no problem, thank you for your answer. I learn from your share, thank you.